# Eclipse autoadd inheritDoc to override

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to auto add

```
/** {@inheritDoc}
     */
```

For: @Override
on file save or  Eclipse auto generated funciton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit **Overriding methods** under *Preferences>Java>Code Style>Code Templates>Comments*

In the same screen, a check box is available with the following info.

> Automatically add comments for new methods and types

Comment: Updated answer. Verified it's working for any new methods being overridden. Please clarify if you are looking for a feature for existing methods.

Comment: Thanks it works for newly created method. How can I make it work of existing functions on save actions/ or something else?